# Ansible inventory file IP extraction for jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to access another host IP for usage in the Jinja2 template. So basically - I need to extract the IP address of another host to use it in my role template. Could you please direct me? Thank you

Example of inventory file, here i need web group host IP (**web_ip**) to use in role for lb group:

```
web:
  hosts:
    web_ip
  vars:
    ansible_user: ...
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ...
lb:
  hosts:
    lb_ip
  vars:
    ansible_user: ..
    ansible_ssh_private_key_file: ..
```

Example of template that will be used for lb host group:

```
upstream web {
  server ${{ web_ip }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Here is the solution that worked for me:

```
{%for host in groups['web']%}{{hostvars[host]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2]}}{% endfor %}
```